# How can i make this function enable on right click of mouse in Jeditable?

Tags: asp.net, jeditable

How can i make this function enable on right click of mouse?

By default it works on left single click, then there appears a drop down, while i want that drop down to appear on right click, is there any way i change that default behavior.

```
 $(".editable_select").editable("http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable/php/save.php", {
        indicator: '<img src="img/indicator.gif">',
        data: "{'Lorem ipsum':'Lorem ipsum','Ipsum dolor':'Ipsum dolor','Dolor sit':'Dolor sit'}",
        type: "select",
        submit: "OK",
        style: "inherit",
        submitdata: function () {
            return { id: 2 };
        }
```

you can see more from here, `http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable/default.html`

look for Inlined select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is to only enable jEditable on right click. You can achieve this by taking care of three steps:

1. detect right clicks
2. enable jEditable in the event handler
3. disable jEditable after editing is fininshed

Something like the following should work:

```
$('#editable').mousedown(function(event) {
    if (event.which != 3) return;
    event.preventDefault();

    $(this).editable('url', {
        ...
        type: "select",
        onreset: function() {
            this.parent().editable('destroy');
        }
    }).click();
});
```

See this in action: http://jsfiddle.net/william/2wBEW/.

In that example, I used `oncontextmenu="return false"` to prevent the default context menu on right clicks. Note that, it is non-standard and cannot be expected to work on all browsers.